# Code Slows Website Down, possible error?

Tags: php, wordpress, web, share, slowdown

This code works, however for unknown reasons, my website loads in 1 second, and when this php is added, it takes 24 seconds. I am still trying to workout why its slowing it down so much, i understand the more lines of code you have the slower things can be by miller seconds, but this is 24 seconds, and looking to fix this even though the script works, I've check with server and nothing technical wrong, its when this code is added, therefore need to correct why this is happening and speed this code up.

```
<?
class shareCount
{
    private $url, $timeout;
    function __construct($url, $timeout = 10)
    {
        $this->url     = rawurlencode($url);
        $this->timeout = $timeout;
    }

    function get_tweets()
    {
        $json_string = $this->file_get_contents_curl('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' . $this->url);
        $json        = json_decode($json_string, true);
        return isset($json['count']) ? intval($json['count']) : 0;
    }

    function get_fb()
    {
        $json_string = $this->file_get_contents_curl('http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls=' . $this->url);
        $json        = json_decode($json_string, true);
        return isset($json[0]['total_count']) ? intval($json[0]['total_count']) : 0;
    }

    function get_plusones()
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://clients6.google.com/rpc");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"' . rawurldecode($this->url) . '","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-type: application/json'
        ));
        $curl_results = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $json = json_decode($curl_results, true);
        return isset($json[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count']) ? intval($json[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count']) : 0;
    }

    private function file_get_contents_curl($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
        $cont = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_error($ch)) {
            die(curl_error($ch));
        }
        return $cont;
    }
}
?>

<div class="entry-share-buttons">
    <div class="share share_size_large share_type_facebook"><span class="share__count"><?php echo $obj->get_fb(); ?></span><a class="share__btn" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink()?>" data-url="<?php the_permalink()?>" data-text="<?php the_title() ?>" target="_blank">Like</a></div>
    <div class="share share_size_large share_type_twitter"><span class="share__count"><?php echo $obj->get_tweets(); ?></span><a class="share__btn" href="http://www.twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=<?php the_permalink()?>" data-url="<?php the_permalink()?>" data-text="<?php the_title() ?>" target="_blank">Tweet</a></div>
    <div class="share share_size_large share_type_email"><span class="share__count"><?php echo $obj->get_plusones(); ?></span><a class="share__btn" href="http://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink()?>" data-url="<?php the_permalink()?>" data-text="<?php the_title() ?>" target="_blank">Email</a></div>
    <div class="share share_size_large share_type_comment"><span class="share__count"><?php comments_popup_link( __( '0' ), __( '1' ), __( '%' ) ); ?></span><a class="share__btn" href="#">Comment</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're making three curl connections when you run this code. These are going to be made one after another - try disabling them one by one to see if one is especially slow; otherwise, I'd suggest putting some caching in place so that you're running the code on every page load

Comment: did what you said and Google + is the one slowing it down dramatically, still not amazing, but works better

Answer (score 1):

I have ran into this same issue recently. The page had many links to download like/share count data from FB and Twitter and page speed decreased dramatically.

The best way I found to solve this issue was to create a table inside a database (if you prefer save it as flat file xml/json that u can update that works too) with the parameters for the information that needs to be refreshed (url/urls).

Write a separate application that runs either as a service or as a scheduled task that you can put a trigger on and set the amount of refreshing you need and thats that.

Real simple, basically you take the load off of the client and put it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lays with the external requests to Twitter, Facebook and Google which are terribly slow. Nothing you can do about that.

What you can do is cache the amount of likes, shares and +. So that the next visitor doesn't have to wait for the slow API's of Twitter, Facebook and Google.

Comment: Also to add to this. Facebook, Google, Twitter, etc. do not like scripts to always hit them without a cache and they have implement features to stop this. Example Google Maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits

Comment: He can amend his code so that it's run as a cronjob, and that updates the numbers. The customer-facing code reads figures from a database, while the cronjob runs every so often and updates those figures. That removes the slow running code from the customer side.

Comment: @andrewsi please would you be able to enlighten me to this, as its something that I've been banging my head against all day :/

Comment: @user3348182 - in brief, what you need to do is take the code in your question, and tweak it. Instead of printing the results from the functions, save them to a database instead. That's all that that program needs to do - make the curl connections, and save the output. The customer facing code just selects the values from the table, and displays those. You can use cron to run the first code every so often, say every hour. Does that help any?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are making numerous connection to other websites and grabbing data from it. There is not many ways to simplify this.

Comment: Aside from using the front-end asynchronous Share button code that Facebook, Twitter, and Google+ already provide for best practice...